# Почему true==null и false==null оба дают false?

Tags: javascript

Что не так с моими Firefox и Chrome – в обоих браузерах простой тест выдаёт противоречащий здравому смыслу и спецификациям результат:

```
[ true == null, false == null]
/*
false,false
*/
```

От перестановки мест результат не меняется. Точно та же картина с `undefined`:

```
[ undefined == true, undefined == false, undefined == null]
/*
false,false,true
*/
```

Если создавать объекты типа `Boolean`, всё становится как положено:

```
[ new Boolean(null) == true, new Boolean(null) == false]
/*
false,true
*/
```

Comment: null это не значение. ее нелзя сравнивать с значением. А когда создаете `Boolean(null)` он из за отсувствия значения  создается со значением по умолчанию. это `FALSE`. лучше `NULL` проверять отделно.

Comment: @Saidolim вы немного не правы. Проверьте свою теорию вычислением `Boolean("")` и `Boolean("1")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потому что [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)  требует, если `Type(x)` или `Type(y)` являются `Boolean` при сравнении `x == y`, тогда `Boolean` должно быть приведено числу с помощью `ToNumber`, которое конвертирует `true` в `1` и `false` в `+0`.

Если по простому, то в JS нету соответствия между `bool` и `null`. `null` в JS это тип. Поэтому сравнивая его с чем-то другим вы всегда получите `false`.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку и объяснение приведения типов. Насчёт `null` – неточность: `null` это таки значение, единственное для типа `Null`, [как пишут](https://es5.github.io/#x8.2).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp Unfortunately, in JavaScript, the data type of null is an object

Comment: @Suvitruf что говорит о том, что тип данных (название которого возвращает `typeof`) у `null` - `object`. Как, например, и у `{}`. А у `undefined`, например, тип - `undefined`.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы заблуждаетесь. Между null и bool есмть соответствие: null преобразуется в false условных выражениях, как, например, в предложении с if . if( null ) соответствет if ( false )

Comment: @VladfromMoscow как я и сказал, "сравнивая null с чем-то другим вы всегда получите false"

Comment: @Suvitruf Ваше сообщение на самом деле не дает ответа на вопрос. Вы просто константируете факт, ссылаясь на таблицу и неверно делаете заключение, что нет связи между null и bool..

Comment: @Suvitruf а что подразумевается под "чем-то другим"? `undefined` имеет отличный от `null` тип, но `if (null == undefined) alert('1')` таки показывает единицу.

Comment: @Regent а если `if (null === undefined) ` ?

Comment: @Suvitruf так это уже строгое сравнение. С ним, слава богу, проблем нет. Вопрос ведь про нестрогое сравнение. В целом, в ответе выходит три сомнительных момента: 1. "нет соответствия между bool и null" - как писал Vlad from Moscow, `null` таки можно преобразовать к типу `boolean`. Что-нибудь в стиле `if (null)` или `if (!!null == false)`. 2. `null` - это примитивное значение, тип которого - `object`. 3. "сравнивая его с чем-то другим вы всегда получите `false`" - тут надо либо про строгое сравнение упоминать, либо про `undefined`,

Answer (score 4):

Потому что в Javascript `undefined`, `null`, `true` и `false` - это 4 совершенно разных значения.

При преобразовании в boolean первые два превращаются в `false`, так же как `0` и `""` - но это не означает, что они равны `false`!

Comment: Как происходит нестрогое сравнение `==` в JS? Я думал, приводится к какому-то общему типу – к какому?

Comment: @Sergiks зависит от параметров. Там сложный алгоритм (и я его не помню)

Comment: @Sergiks есть милая табличка по этому поводу: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using

Comment: @Regent, неточная табличка, `typeof NaN == number` но все операции сравнения с `NaN` возвращют _false_

Comment: @Grundy а сравнение `NaN` с чем, согласно таблице, должно выдавать `true`?

Comment: ну судя по таблице _Number false false A === B A === ToNumber(B) A === ToNumber(B) A == ToPrimitive(B)_ c сами собой например

Comment: @Regent, а хотя нет, похоже я запутался что вообще показывает табличка :-)

Comment: @Grundy да, таблица достаточно хитрая и далеко не во всех ячейках есть сходу ответ `true` или `false`. Зато компактная получается, и в большинстве случаев ответ сразу или почти сразу виден. В частности, для `NaN == NaN` применяется правило _Number - Number_, что сводится к `A === B`, что в данном случае возвращает `false`. То, как происходит строгое сравнение `NaN` с `NaN` (да и вообще сравнение данных одного типа), действительно выходит за рамки компетенции таблицы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32102/discussion-between-grundy-and-regent).

Answer (score 3):

Это просто надо принять к сведению. Это так называемое "темное" место языка. Оно "темное", потому что другие подходы не менее логичны, чем принятый. И принятое соглашение не выглядит безупречным. Например в предложении `if-else`

```
if ( null ) alert( true );
else alert( false );
```

будет выведено `false`.

Или рассмотрите другой пример

```
var nullValue = Boolean(null);
alert("nullValue == false is " + (nullValue == false));
```

Результатом будет `true`.

При использовании оператора равенства типы `null` и `undefined` не преобразуются в другие типы и равны только самим себе или друг другу.

Поэтому единственные сравнения за исключением сравнений с самими собой где результат сравнения равен `true`, это следующие сравнения:

```
alert("null == undefined is " + ( null == undefined )); // true
alert("undefined == null is " + (undefined == null));  // true
```

Comment: Это предложение – лучшее объяснение: «При использовании оператора равенства типы `null` и `undefined` не преобразуются в другие типы и равны только самим себе или друг другу.» То же, более длинно и запутанно, объясняют [спеки ES5](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) – п.п. 2,3 и 6,7

Comment: @Sergiks Да, если запомнить эту фразу, то "жить станет лучше, жить станет веселей".:)